# In host languages, in what cases can database transactions ensure concurrency correctness?

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

I am wondering in a host language(for example, VB 2013), in what cases can database transactions ensure correctness in concurrency.

For example, in a host language, if I begin a transaction, and then in the transaction I do a query to get a number in the database to a variable that is declared in the host language, and then do another query to get a number in the database to another variable that is declared in the host language, and then I add the two numbers, and then I put the sum to a field of a row of a table in the database, and then I commit the transaction, then, does this program work correctly to add the two numbers and then put the sum to the database, in concurrency situations?

Answer (score 0):

By default, your example probably won't work as intended.  Your db of choice should have some synchronization primitives that could help with this.  A transaction alone will probably not be enough to use.  Something has to tell the db that reading the variable should be synchronized as well as writing.

MySQL allows for locking reads as part of a transaction

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Does PostgreSQL provide support for this?